STM32F401RE Systick problematic
I dont understand why doesn't the systick allow main loop to work? How would I configure it differently so that I get both the systick to trigger and the Main loop simultaneously?
#include "main.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union InterruptFlag flag = { .bits_access.flag=     0,
                             .bits_access.direction=0,
                             .bits_access.debounce= 0,
                             .bits_access.press   = 0}; // Initialize to 0


void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){

        flag.bits_access.flag = !flag.bits_access.flag; // Set the flag to indicate button press event
        EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

};



#define MAX_DUTY 500
#define MIN_DUTY 0
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY 500
volatile uint32_t duty_cycle;
volatile uint16_t incrementer = 1;

Here is just some configuration of the things that let the code function
int main(void){

  TIM2_INIT();
  TIM3_INIT();
  Interrupt_Init();
  SysTick->CTRL = SysTick->CTRL | (1 << 0) | (1 << 1) | (1 << 2);
  SysTick->LOAD = (84000 - 1);  // 100 millisecond
  while (1) {
      //LED_PWM();
      if(flag_check()==true){
          incrementer=0;
      }
     }
}

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    LED_PWM();
}

bool flag_check(){
    return flag.bits_access.flag;
}



void LED_PWM() {
    TIM2->CCR1 = duty_cycle;
    incrementer=1;
    if (duty_cycle >= MAX_DUTY) {
        flag.bits_access.direction = false; // Change direction to decrement
    } else if (duty_cycle <= MIN_DUTY) {
        flag.bits_access.direction = true;  // Change direction to increment
    }

    if (flag.bits_access.direction) {
        duty_cycle += incrementer; // Increment
    } else {
        duty_cycle -= incrementer; // Decrement
    }
}


Messing up with the systick mostly, and the main loop, but to no avail

Your union InterruptFlag flag (and anything else that gets changed in an ISR) needs to be volatile.

Ill switch that up tomorrow morning when I wake up, thanks pmacfarlane, you're a real one.

I dont understand why doesn't the systick allow main loop to work? How do you know that it's the systick and how do you know it does not allow main to work? In other words, what are the expectations and how does the observed behaviour differ from them?

Also, are you sure you want the flags be in union? Shouldn't they be in struct?

@pmacfarlane They are volatile now, and the change still doesnt occur, do you have any other idea?

@wek It was more of an assumption to be honest... I had an expectation that every clock tick, I'd have my led PWM duty cycle change, eitherpositive or negative, and in the main loop I'd have something to check if the flag has changed, if it had, my LED would stop increasing/decreasing its brightness, this is how my mentor wanted me to implement some sort of multi threading I guess

There was a silly error in the LED_PWM function that said every time it starts up that the incrementer was set to 1, and with that, the counter wouldnt ever stop, since every time the function initiated, the PWM would increase by the said incrementer, fixed code is here
union InterruptFlag flag = { .bits_access.flag=     0,
                             .bits_access.direction=0,
                             .bits_access.debounce= 0,
                             .bits_access.press   = 0}; // Initialize to 0


void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){

        flag.bits_access.flag = !flag.bits_access.flag; // Set the flag to indicate button press event
        EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

};



#define MAX_DUTY 500
#define MIN_DUTY 0
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY 500
volatile uint32_t duty_cycle=0;
volatile uint16_t incrementer = 1;

int main(void){

  TIM2_INIT();
  TIM3_INIT();
  Interrupt_Init();
  SysTick->CTRL = SysTick->CTRL | (1 << 0) | (1 << 1) | (1 << 2);
  SysTick->LOAD = (84000 - 1);  // 100 millisecond
  while (1) {
      if(flag_check()==true){
          incrementer=0;
      }
     }
}

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    LED_PWM();
}

bool flag_check(){
    return flag.bits_access.flag;
}



void LED_PWM() {
    TIM2->CCR1 = duty_cycle;
    incrementer=flag.bits_access.flag;
    if (duty_cycle >= MAX_DUTY) {
        flag.bits_access.direction = false; // Change direction to decrement
    } else if (duty_cycle <= MIN_DUTY) {
        flag.bits_access.direction = true;  // Change direction to increment
    }

    if (flag.bits_access.direction) {
        duty_cycle += incrementer; // Increment
    } else {
        duty_cycle -= incrementer; // Decrement
    }

}



